# Using two-way data binding with managed RealmObject in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, realm, realm-java

**Background:** I am using `io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0` for showing a list of items. Each row consists of three `TextViews`  and two `EditText` fields. These three `TextViews` text are set from `realm` schema. I am using two way data binding for `EditText` like:

```
<EditText
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:inputType="number"
 android:text="@={Conversion.toString(offline.inputUI)}" />
```

This `offline` is the schema that extends `RealmObject` with two `@Ignore` fields which correspond to the two `EditText`. Vales are reflected in the `offline` model when user types.

**Problem:** When I scroll past the screen `EditText` values are lost. If four rows are visible at a time on the screen and user feed the `EditText` and scrolls for the next four rows and if revisits the first four rows values of all `EditText` are lost. This is happening because of **zero copy design** and I understand it. However if I remove the `@Ignore` from `EditText` then an exception is thrown that you cannot perform transaction outside ....etc.

**Desired output** How to avoid the values of `EditText` vanishing while scrolling and taking the benefit of realm **zero copy design**. Also, save the values of `EditText` in realm in real time as user types or after user has left the `EditText`. **Is it really possible or not?** . Do I need to change my current approach. If I use frequent write transactions when focus is changed from `EditText`, will it drain the battery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to leverage Realms zero-copy architecture, the only solution is to persist all the data you want to have saved, but 2-way databinding with automatic transactions are not supported automatically right now.

You could make it work if you added transactions to all setters used by databinding. But depending on how often you are saving data, it could still result in introducing jank to your UI.

It is a problem we are thinking about, but we will not be able to provide any solutions in the short-term.

I'm afraid, that no matter what, there isn't any "easy" choice.

Note, battery drain is not the issue, but that you will be writing to disk very frequently.

Comment: Thank-you, at last. I was expecting the same except for battery drain.  This would be very cool feature. It would be good if you could shed some light on point 2) of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44842541/2870088