# Update specific realm model properties?

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

How to update only some realm model properties and instead of trying to save complete realm model again and again using `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`.

```
public class User extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
public String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
private String          name;
private int             age;

@Ignore
private int             sessionId;

// Standard getters & setters generated by your IDE…
public String getName() { return name; }
public void   setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
public int    getAge() { return age; }
public void   setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
public int    getSessionId() { return sessionId; }
public void   setSessionId(int sessionId) { this.sessionId = sessionId; 
}
}
```

**1)** If `User` is already persisted in the realm and I only want to update `name` using primary key `id`. Something like `Update name only where id = "someValue"` in User.

**2)** So, what if there are 500 realm model and only one property of each realm model is changed. Should updating complete model in realm via `copyToRealmOrUpdate` will be faster or iterating all the realm results model and finding the item first and then updating the single property only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final String userId = ...;
try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
        User user = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", userId).findFirst();
        if(user != null) {
            user.setName("set name");
        }
    });
}
```

You can obtain a managed RealmObject by id and then modify its property inside a transaction.

Comment: Thank-you, I knew this way but I wasn't just confirmed. I thought that there could be some other way.  It would be of great help if you could just answer the second part.

Comment: I'd just iterate with `for(Obj obj : realm.where(Obj.class).findAll()) { ... }` inside a transaction. I've been campaigning for a `setValue()` method for a while now but ["batch update" is still not in yet.](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/762)

Comment: This concludes the second question with first find the items and then update the relevant property in realm model within transaction block while iterating over it. Thank-you

Answer (score 3):

You can change model properties inside the `Transaction()` if you have Created Object through Realm or get After some query on Realm database.

Now you have a instance of this class created by realm like:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
User user = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", "your id").findFirst();// since you are serching on the basis of primary key there will be only one object
```

So when you want to change its property, can change into Transaction like:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
user.setName("abc");
realm.commitTransaction();
```

It will change the particular property no need to call `copyToRealmOrUpdate()`.

OR

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
       RealmResults<User> users = realm
            .where(User.class)
            .equalTo("id", "your id")// or some other condition
            .findAll();
        for(User user : users) {
          user.setName("abc");
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it help!!

Comment: I may not be clear with the question, so I have updated the same.

Comment: same can be achieved this way,, first find the particular model instance by where() clause and then change the name transaction.

Comment: Thank-you and I understand the above approach but what if there are 500 real model and only one property of each is updated. Please check the updated question for detail.

Comment: I am upvoting because you suggested the answer for the first part. Thank-you